# Accessing data downloaded via catkin_download_test_data

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin's document "[Downloading test data](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/downloading_test_data.html#downloading-test-data-2)" recommends to specify the location to store the downloaded data by `DESTINATION` option in `catkin_download_test_data` macro, so that the data can be accessed in `roslaunch` by `$(find your_package)` during the tests.

While using `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX` in DESTINATION certainly downloads the data at the intended location under `devel` folder, however, in the workspaces built by normal ways (e.g. `catkin_make`, `catkin build` with limited options  etc.), `rospack find` looks for the specified package under `src` instead of `devel` AFAIK, which results in the test not being able to find the downloaded data.

Is there a way to access the data without changing much of workspace build process?

I'm pretty sure the catkin doc above is using [velodyne](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) package as an example, where the tests successfully access the downloaded data by [a chain of complicated `catkin_make_isolated` commands](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/594d0be6e8b1c29f953ed45007b5c4b2c7a7057a/.travis.yml#L29_L31), which is not ideal in my case.

---

UPDATE1. Is `catkin run_tests` not enough to run test target? That's what I do in [this PR](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/pull/106) (build script is [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/blob/10d80843e66d565e7e5e0ae2b0e2718eee68aad6/industrial_ci/src/tests/source_tests.sh#L192)) and fails (e.g. [here](https://travis-ci.org/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/jobs/198226437#L2819) saying the file is not found).

---

UPDATE2. I conclude in the end that the way mentioned in Catkin's doc I referenced at the top should work as expected. In my very own case, `rospack` had not been able to find the downloaded file simply because there was a [typo](https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar/pull/106/commits/751cb14e8867080b3f99269a814473402fc6d00f#diff-2dfc21243b6b6d41cd0325cd9683d490R16) in the path name :/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253787/accessing-data-downloaded-via-catkin_download_test_data/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-02-06**:
I don't think it is enough to say just `catkin run_tests`. Instead you can try `catkin build` and then `catkin run_tests`. It could also be that your test targets do not depend on the download target, so the file is not downloaded by make before trying to run the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work, see:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/228
https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/141

`roslaunch` should look in both the source and devel spaces in this case. The "chain of complicated `catkin_make_isolated` commands" is simply building in three separate steps. The first one builds everything but tests (the "all" target in make), the second one ensures the tests are built (the "tests" target in make), and the third runs the tests. I would expect you could just do that last one. I think you might be conflating the two items: find the file and how you're building your workspace. You will have to manually run the test targets as they are not part of the "all" target.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried to download it to  `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test`?
Update: just evaluates to `share`, so it might not help.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1